A movie about a boy who after applying a solution to his bald head his hair will not stop growing
This was a kids' movie that I saw back in the late 80s/early 90s.
It involved a brother and a sister, I think or maybe a boy and his friend. The boy was scared by, I think, a ghost or pair of ghosts. This results in him losing all of his hair, going completed bald.
A scene later shows him playing in a football/soccer game whilst wearing a wig. A larger 'bully' type character proceeds to tear off the boy's wig during the game. He runs home whilst the other players, from both teams, chase him singing a song. One of the lyrics talks about a boiled egg?
The boy later meets a something (perhaps one of the ghosts that original scared him?) that provides him with a solution/recipe that if applied to his head will make his hair grow back.
It does but his hair won't stop growing. Somehow this results in him being kidnapped by an old man who cuts the boy's hair to make special, perhaps magic?, paint brushes. He then proceeds to kidnap other children to work in his paint brush factory.
In order to stop the children escaping he ties fishing line to his fingers and across the factory, so if the lines tug on his fingers he wakes up.
The sister* manages to sneak into the factory, or is captured, and by using one of the paintbrushes to 'see' where the invisible lines are she manages to free all the children. Including her brother. 
The brother's hair growing problem is, I think, solved by being scared by the ghosts again.
*could be a friend rather than a sister.

Sounds like The Peanut Butter Solution from 1985. From Wiki:

Michael Baskin is an average 11-year old boy. [...] Upon hearing the news that an abandoned mansion has recently burned down, Michael and his friend Connie decide to explore the remains. Outside the mansion, Connie dares Michael to take a look inside, leading to a frightening encounter with the ghosts of its homeless inhabitants who had died in the fire. Michael does not know this yet, but his fearsome run in with the ghosts has given him a mysterious illness simply known as "The Fright". Michael wakes up the next morning to find out that "The Fright" has made him lose all of his hair. After a failed attempt with a wig (his wig was pulled off by an older boy during a fight in a soccer game), the ghosts visit Michael in his sleep and give him the recipe of a magical formula for hair growth, the main ingredient of which is peanut butter.

Then his hair won't stop growing. Here's the trailer (the wig incident appears around 0:25):




That's it! That's the one! Thanks for that. I've mentioned it to other people before and they swore I must have been dreaming.
